# Is there a way to prevent re-create fragment in bottomNavigation when using android navigation component

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using bottom navigation with the android navigation component
when I clicked on an item that is selected before, the system creates a new instance of that fragment, replace that on view and remove the last fragment.
I want to prevent re-creating fragments and ignore user clicking

this is my menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/historyFragment"
    android:title="@string/main_records"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_records"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_pulse"
    android:title="@string/main_measure" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/settingFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
    android:title="@string/main_setting"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Comment: Last time I checked, this was a known issue.

Comment: *I want to prevent re-creating fragments and ignore user clicking* why?

Comment: There is a trick to do achieve that is by using ViewPager and disabled swipe gesture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Version `2.2.0-alpha02` this is a known issue and `NavigationUI` does not check this out of the box. However, there is a hacky way to achieve what you wanted:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->

            for(menuItem in bottomNav.menu.iterator()){
                menuItem.isEnabled = true
            }

            val menu = bottomNav.menu.findItem(destination.id)
            menu?.isEnabled = false
}
```

Here, I am disabling the menuItem if it's id is the same to the destination id. But at first I am enabling all the menuItem as one item might be disabled by previous iteration.

After this, to get the style you need to set a color to the disabled menuItem. You can do this by setting following colorState

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent" />

    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</selector>
```

Finally you need to use this color state in the BottomNav

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_color_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_color_state"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom"/>
```

This is not the best solution. But this would work.

Hope, this would help you.

Comment: You can add this in bottom navigation bar

`navView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
            // do nothing here, it will prevent recreating same fragment
        

}`